# How to remove extended attributes from all files in a folder on mac

Tags: macos, automation

i'm trying to remove the extended attributes from some files (where froms) in a folder on my mac.
I could not find a solution for that. Is there a way to remove the attributes from all files in a folder?
Kind regards Bijo

Comment: Careful - some files keep data in the resource fork, such as compiled scripts and some older images, so as mentioned in some of the answers to the linked topic below, it is better to check or just remove the `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` attribute using the `-d` option.

Comment: As @red_menace says, and other metadata will get destroyed if you are not selective about which xattr - e.g. Finder tags.

Answer (score 5):

> ### To Remove All Extended Attributes On Many Files
>
> To recursively remove extended attributes on all files in a directory,
> combine the `-c` "clear" flag with the `-r` recursive flag:
>
> ```
> xattr -rc /path/to/directory
> ```
>
> Open `Terminal.app` and start typing `xattr -rc`  , include a trailing
> space, and then then drag the file or folder to the `Terminal.app`
> window and it will automatically add the full path with proper
> escaping.

---

Source: Taken form cwd's answer to: [How do I remove the “extended attributes” on a file in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x/17491622#17491622)

Answer (score 4):

A less destructive command that only remove the attribute you (don't) want is:

```
xattr -rd com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms /path/to/directory
```